# How can I fix a bitter raw leek soup?

Tags: soup, vegetarian, raw

My son just got his braces adjusted and in a panic to make him a lunch for school, I made the following soup in my vitamix with what I had on hand. The problem is that the soup is very bitter (raw leek I suspect). I usually sauté the leeks first but didn't have time this morning. If I cook it on the stove, will the bitter taste go away? What if I blended in a head of raw broccoli?

Here are my ingredients:
1 raw leek...stalk and all, 
1 small avocado,
2 stalks of celery,
About 8 cherry tomatoes,
½ cup of potato and garlic mash from a previous dinner,
about 1 cup of ready made chicken broth.

The consistency is awesome. I just need to fix the bitter taste and nastiness of eating raw onions! Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Oh man. Who are you and will you be my mom? What an amazing lunch. I was lucky to get a peanut butter sandwich.

Answer (score 4):

Raw leeks are quite strong and will mellow if cooked, so get it up to temperature for awhile and see where you get. I suspect that will get you much of the way there. If not, some mild acidity will help, adding a squeeze of lemon juice may do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Bitterness is best counteracted by salt, so give it a good seasoning. You might also try adding a little mild vinegar like white wine or cider vinegar.

Comment: It's already fairly salty because of the store bought chicken broth and the celery. Also, the whole family hates all sorts of vinegar, so this wouldn't be my first choice. I guess I can't just cook it? Any other options?

Comment: Well, you have some bitter ingredients in there - celery and avocado especially. Cooking won't make a great deal of difference since everything is already blended and you won't be able to caramelise anything. You don't need to put _much_ vinegar in - not so much that you'd really taste it - just enough to counteract the bitterness. Otherwise I'm afraid it's time to make another meal!