# Fixing a beef broth with too much celery seed

Tags: soup, broth

I cooked a large crock pot of beef bone broth. I didn't have any veggies so I used garlic salt, onion powder, celery seed and bay leaves with my beef bones and about 4 quarts of water.  I didn't measure anything, just poured spices in.

It has been simmering now for 18+ hours. I decided to taste and it is very bitter from all the celery seed. Now what can I do to try and fix the taste from all,the celery seed? I really hate for the broth to go to waste.

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/44314/23376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitterness is generally corrected with a combination of salt, sweetness and/or fats.

You mention that don't have any veg at the moment -- perhaps put the stock aside or freeze until you can pick some up. Some sweet veg like parsnip and carrots could probably rescue this stock for you. Sweet herbs like basil or spices like cloves might also work, depending on what you like.

References for flavor balancing:
 - http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/wordofmouth/2013/nov/19/balance-flavours-salt-sweet-bitter-sour-umami
 - http://lifehacker.com/learn-to-make-any-dish-you-cook-better-with-the-science-1477864259
 - http://academiewines.com/blog/2010/05/14/strategies-for-fixing-your-dish/

A herb and spice reference that might give you some ideas:
 - http://www.thekitchn.com/quick-guide-to-every-herb-and-spice-in-the-cupboard-108770

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely try adding some carrots or parsnips.  I added some salt, but still not where I could drink like a cup of broth if needed.

Comment: @Christine -- good luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for me the first time, I forget to roast the bones before making the stock. It is a completely different product without the roasting. It resulted in a beef broth that was unpalatable.

The deal with the celery taste, strain the liquid to get the celery seed out.

Then dilute with more water, to hopefully tamp down that very strong taste.

Lastly, I would add some vegetables if possible. I’d suggest carrots and onions. They should impart some other flavors to offset the celery seed taste.